# Electrostatics Potential Energy Calculation for a System of Charges

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

Im using an example to explain my doubt:

Suppose i have 6 equal charges of charge q placed at the vertices of a hexagon of side length a.
Ive found a method in my textbook to calculate the electrostatic potential energy of the system as:

∫ Vdq for all charges where V is the potential at the position of the particle "while the system is being made" (I think this means that if i am making my hexagon system and bringing a third charge then i would only consider potential at its position due to the two previous charges present there)

Or

1/2 ∫ Vdq where V is the final potential if each particle after the entire system is made. (in this case that would be 0.5* 6 * Vq where V is potential at any vertices)

How did we derive the second formula and how is it correct? Can we use it in all cases?

Comment: Do it both ways and you will find that for this situation both methods work but it is generally not true.  The situation you are dealing with is highly symmetrical whereas in most cases that is not true.  to make thinks easier I would suggest try three charges at the corners of an equilateral triangle and three charges with equal separation along a straight line.